# How to use variable to implement the updateOne's $set operation path?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var _type;
switch (type) {
  case 0:
    _type = `"$user_list.GTA"`;
    break;
  case 1:
    _type = `"$user_list.DOTA"`;
    break;
  case 2:
    _type = `"$user_list.LOL"`;
    break;
  default:
    _type = null;
}

await game
.collection("game")
.updateOne(
  { game_id },
  { $set: { _type: user_id } },
  (err, result) => {
    // console.log(result);
  }
);
```

I am trying to do `{ $set: {'$user_list.DOTA: user_id}}` but using variable `_type`. If I do the `console.log(_type)` then it returns `"$user_list.DOTA"`. However, in my database, the `user_id` is added into the new field called `_type` like `_type: 'usussseeer'`.

Is there any way that I can use the value `_type` to set the update path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- don't include `$` in any field name,

```
var _type;
switch (type) {
  case 0:
    _type = `"user_list.GTA"`;
    break;
  case 1:
    _type = `"user_list.DOTA"`;
    break;
  case 2:
    _type = `"user_list.LOL"`;
    break;
  default:
    _type = null;
}
```

- use array bracket in key name `[_type]`,

```
await game.collection("game").updateOne(
  { game_id },
  { $set: { [_type]: user_id } },
  (err, result) => {
    // console.log(result);
  }
);
```